# Is there any way in pandas to merge two table in a nested way

Tags: python, pandas

`table 1`

```
table1 = df.groupby('year').agg(
    Total_Brands=('brand_name', 'nunique'),
    Total_Users=('user_id', 'nunique'),
    Total_Stories=('story_id', 'nunique'),
    Total_Sessions=('video_id', 'nunique'),
    Total_Nodes=('node_key', 'nunique')
)
```

`table 2`

```
table2 = df.groupby(['year','brand_name']).agg(
    Total_Users=('user_id', 'nunique'),
    Total_Stories=('story_id', 'nunique'),
    Total_Sessions=('video_id', 'nunique'),
    Total_Nodes=('node_key', 'nunique')
)
```

`table 1`

```
    Total_Brands    Total_Users Total_Stories   Total_Sessions  Total_Nodes
year                    
2018        12              324              101          1431       0
2019        19              859              576          17453      0
2020        22              5062         890          98101      0
2021        29              9818         2584         208461       2784
2022        31              2148         1548         39241    1959
```

`table 2`

```
           Total_Users  Total_Stories   Total_Sessions  Total_Nodes
year    brand_name              
2018    ABC         2         4              9               0
        CDE         4         12         24              0
        FGH         6         19         172         0
        JKL         2          1         5               0
        MNO         34        32         376         0
```

By using these two table I want to join both the tables in a nested form and diplay count of values as column name for nested table. e.g.:

```
2018    12 Brands   324 Users   101 Stories 1431 Sessions   0 Nodes                                 
    ABC             2                4               9               0
        CDE             4               12              24               0
        FGH             6               19             172               0
        JKL             2                1               5               0
        MNO            34               32             376               0
2019    19 Brands       859 Users   576 Stories 17453 Sessions  0 Nodes
        ...             ...             ...             ...             ...
```

I need this type of output using python pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(pd.concat([df1.astype(str).add(' '+df1.columns.str[6:])
               .rename(columns={'Total_Brands': 'brand_name'})
               .set_index('brand_name', append=True),
            df2])
   .sort_index(kind='stable')
)
```

Output:

```
                Total_Users Total_Stories   Total_Sessions Total_Nodes
year brand_name                                                       
2018 12 Brands    324 Users   101 Stories    1431 Sessions     0 Nodes
     ABC                  2             4                9           0
     CDE                  4            12               24           0
     FGH                  6            19              172           0
     JKL                  2             1                5           0
     MNO                 34            32              376           0
2019 19 Brands    859 Users   576 Stories   17453 Sessions     0 Nodes
2020 22 Brands   5062 Users   890 Stories   98101 Sessions     0 Nodes
2021 29 Brands   9818 Users  2584 Stories  208461 Sessions  2784 Nodes
2022 31 Brands   2148 Users  1548 Stories   39241 Sessions  1959 Nodes
```

Comment: Your expected output is not so clear as it is poorly formatted. Can you provide a `DataFrame` constructor of the expected output?

Comment: I'm sorry but a screenshot is not reproducible data. Also, you didn't provide user_id, story_id in your inputs

Comment: What you want should be easy to do, but I need fully reproducible and complete example data

Comment: Why don't you provide a minimal reproducible example in the form of a DataFrame constructor for `df`? It's pointless to ask again the same question, this is not how this site works. Edit your current question with more details.